# asp.net jquery script not running after postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, postback

I've spent several hours searching for an answer, but cannot seem to make this work.
I know javascript/jquery in asp.net only works firs time if you have an updatepanel, so I need it to make work also when you page on the gridview.
I've found out you need to put some code within the updatepanel to refresh the javascript everytime you postback.
So this is the code I tried, which doesn't work (gives a 'BindEvents not defined' error)

Here is the code (shorted) that doesn't work:

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                Sys.Application.add_load(BindEvents); ' reload jquery again after postback 

            </script> 

             <div id="div_GRIDVIEW" class="div_Gridview" clientidmode="Static"  runat="server">
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1">
...grid data
</asp:GridView>
 </div>
some more code....

             <script type="text/javascript">
                 function BindEvents() {

                     $("table.STD_GridView tr").mouseover(function (event) {

                         var color = $(this).css("background-color");
                         $(this).css("background", "#f6f6f6");
                         $(this).bind("mouseout", function () {
                             $(this).css("background", color);
                         })
                     }
                 )
                 }
           </script>
</body>
</html>
```

However if you add the scripts within the updatepanel
 area as follows, it works perfectly. The thing is that I don't want to put the javascript/jquery code within the update panel, but at the bottom, because I have lots of javascript/jquery code (here is just an example)

Any guidance will be appreciated

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Sys.Application.add_load(BindEvents); ' triggers jquery again after postback of gridview'

        function BindEvents() {

            $("table.STD_GridView tr").mouseover(function (event) {

                var color = $(this).css("background-color");
                $(this).css("background", "#f6f6f6");
                $(this).bind("mouseout", function () {
                    $(this).css("background", color);
                })
            }
        )
        }


    </script> 

     <div id="div_GRIDVIEW" class="div_Gridview" clientidmode="Static"  runat="server">
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue recently when my Bootstrap Tabs and other items no longer worked after adding an UpdatePanel. Items has to be reinitialized.

I solved this with two items. First reload all the scripts on postback.  Second re-init any jQuery features.

A) Reload all your scripts on every postback. I use a customer class to load CSS and JavaScript vs. the bundle config... This is in the page_load of the master page and fires each time.

```
 ClientScripts.AddClientScripts(Page);
```

B) The Client Script Load

```
public static class ClientScripts
    {
        public static void AddClientScripts(Page page)
        {
            //Making it Month instead to limit downloads
            string ID = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();

            //Change this if pushing CSS changes during the day
            string VerNo = "41";

            ID = ID + VerNo;

            AddJavaScriptFile(page, "Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js", ID);
            AddJavaScriptFile(page, "Scripts/bootstrap.min.js", ID);
            AddJavaScriptFile(page, "Scripts/DevExpress.js", ID);            
            AddJavaScriptFile(page, "Scripts/ValidateNumber.js", ID);            

            AddCSSFile(page, "Content/bootstrap.min.css", ID);
            AddCSSFile(page, "font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css", ID);         

        }
        private static void AddJavaScriptFile(Page page, string path, string id)
        {            
            //var Key = path.Replace("Scripts/", "");
            //Key = Key.Replace(".js", "");
            //page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(Key, path);

            path = page.ResolveUrl("~/" + path) + "?id=" + id;

            //Add to header
            HtmlGenericControl child = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
            child.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
            child.Attributes.Add("src", path);
            page.Header.Controls.Add(child);

            //Line break
            page.Header.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("\r\n"));
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Add CSS File
        /// </summary>
        private static void AddCSSFile(Page page, string path, string id)
        {
            path = page.ResolveUrl("~/" + path) + "?id=" + id;

            HtmlLink lnk = new HtmlLink();
            lnk.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
            lnk.Attributes.Add("href", path);
            lnk.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
            page.Header.Controls.Add(lnk);

            //Line break
            page.Header.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("\r\n"));
        }
    }
```

C) There are times you have to re-init components like Bootstrap. Add the following inside your UpdatePanel.

Sys.Application.add_load will call a "BindEvents" JavaScript function to reinitialize jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       Sys.Application.add_load(BindEvents);
</script>
```

B) BindEvents: This is what I have in my Bind Events

```
    function BindEvents() { 

    //--- START Popovers with x -----
    $('.popoverThis').popover({
        html: true,
        placement: 'right',
        content: function () {
            return $($(this).data('contentwrapper')).html();
        }
    });
    $('.popoverThis').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }); 
    $(document).click(function (e) {
        if (($('.popover').has(e.target).length == 0) || $(e.target).is('.close')) {
            $('.popoverThis').popover('hide');
        }
    });

    //POPOVER --- TOP ---
    $('.popoverThisTop').popover({
        html: true,
        placement: 'top',
        content: function () {
            return $($(this).data('contentwrapper')).html();
        }
    });
    $('.popoverThisTop').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(document).click(function (e) {
        if (($('.popover').has(e.target).length == 0) || $(e.target).is('.close')) {
            $('.popoverThisTop').popover('hide');
        }
    });

    //--- END Popovers with x -----

    //Accordion
    $('#accordion').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
        //do something...
    })
    $('#accordion .accordion-toggle').click(function (e) {
        var chevState = $(e.target).siblings("i.indicator").toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-up');
        $("i.indicator").not(chevState).removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-down").addClass("glyphicon-chevron-up");
    });
}
```

Comment: hi and thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it's a bit over my knowledge on the subject I I am unable to understand how to implemented in my project. I was hoping for a more easier solution but I guess it doesn't exist. Thanks again

Comment: You can use ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(UpdatePanel1, UpdatePanel1.GetType(), "jscript", jscript,false); in the PAGE_LOAD to attach the script to the update panel if you do not want to code it in line. Either way either load all the scripts on each page load or load it inside of the update panel.